# mongodb replica doesn't choose primary after a failover

Tags: mongodb, replication

I'm using 3 Linux servers that runs mongodb. I want to use replication with 1 primary and 2 secondaries. I succeeded with setting it up, and when I shut down the primary I saw that one of the secondaries was chosen as primary.
So now I have left with 1 primary and 1 secondary.
When I shut down the primary I am left with secondary which doesn't elected as primary.

I have read the documentation and search the web but I couldn't find anything about it. Why does the secondary not being elected as primary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of reasons the last member is not being elected but the biggest one is that you require a majority of configured, voting, members to be online and voting in order for MongoDB to know that it is not:

- A Network Partition
- Or a problem within that `mongod`

If a majority of members are offline MongoDB will, naturally, stop writes to the set since it cannot make a best guess at the current state of the replica set.

Once you have a majority offline you will need to intervene manually: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/reconfigure-replica-set-with-unavailable-members/

Comment: It's written in the documentation that it's not recommended to use the 'force' method in an automatic script. How then can I select a primary in case I am left with only 1 member which is a secondary?

Comment: @Candroid that is really the only way, I mean it is not normally recommended to run on a single member of a replica set, as such the whole idea if what you want to do is not technically recommended.